# SQL server connection happening on different port without specifying port in connection string

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection

There is a SQL Server instance on server which is listening on different port 1550 other than 1433. When I am trying to connect it from other server without specifying the port number in connection string the connection is working fine. I want to understand how is that happening? Is it something to do with SQL browser service? This setup was done by someone else which I am not aware of.

Also I have checked the firewall, there is no port forwarding in place. Can anyone explain how that is happening?

Comment: Are you specifying the server name alone (no instance name)? In that case, it may be an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client) is configured on the client.

Comment: @DanGuzman I am not specifying the instance name. its just the server name.

Comment: When you say client machine, does it mean the machine which is trying to connect the SQL server? If Yes then I cannot find the SQL server configuration manager there.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean by client, the "other server" in your question. Do you not see `SqlServerManager*.msc` in `C:\Windows\System32`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, The client server is having a .net application hosted which is connecting the SQL server. There is not SQL server manager installed on client machine. Thanks

Comment: Check to see if there are registry entries for an alias, I found [this](https://sql-play.com/2012/02/01/create-sql-server-aliases-using-registry-editor/) but the location may vary by version. Or you could install SSMS for the UI. AFAIK, an alias is the only way to connect to a non-default port.

Comment: I will definitely check this.

Comment: I have added the answer. @DanGuzman thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was the case of server migration, The database was migrated to new server and password hash were not synced properly. One of our DBA had ran the query to auto_fix it but that query didn't work. Later on when he updated the password hash again everything started working.